# Spring Entity Listener registration

Tags: spring, jpa, entity, listener

I want to register JPA entity listener without using annotation `@EntityListeners` and without xml configuration.
Is there is a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you look at this? https://deepintojee.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/spring-managed-event-listeners-with-jpa/

Comment: this helps add entity listener for all entities, but I am wondering if there is a way to register listener for concrete entity.